# How to disable the overscrolling-effect for ListBoxes/ScrollViewer in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to disable the overscrolling-effect for ListBoxes or ScrollViewers? I think the effect is also called "rubber-band-effect".

I'd like to completely disable it 
or to disable it, if there are only a few items in the container, and re-enable it if there are more items in the container than the number of items that fit on one screen.

The list of installed application has exactly the behavior I want to achieve. There is no overscrolling.

[image: list of installed applications]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability doesn't appear to be exposed at this stage by the API.

I would think carefully before trying to do this also, as it will be behaviour that is consistant throughout the platform - as it is on other platforms.

Comment: The list of installed applications has exactly that behavior without overscrolling. So it would be consistent with the platform. Any idea how I could achieve the same behavior of the list of installed apps?

Comment: The list of installed applications overscrolls on the device I try it on. This doesn't happen in the emulator though.

Comment: There is no way to disable the bump/bounce effect, though it might be technically possible by trying to counteract the transforms, it would be a massive undertaking unfortunately.